# How can i return an object with a dictionary property from dapper repo call

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have an object Invoice that has the following:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    
    public IDictionary<int, double> Variables { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a dapper repository query as this:

```
const string query = @"select InvoiceId, GroupId, VariableId, VariableValue
                       From Invoices;";


var result = ExecuteQuery<Invoice>(query, null);
```

What I am trying to get is the above query will return a flat dataset where I want to group by InvoiceId, GroupId and then put all the VariableId, VariableValues into the dictionary.

How can I achieve this with LINQ select many ToDictionary along those lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var invoiceDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Invoice>(); 

var list = connection.Query<Invoice, IDictionary<int, double>, Invoice>(
        sql,
        (invoice, variables) =>
        {
            Invoice invoiceEntry;

            if (!invoiceDictionary.TryGetValue(invoice.InvoiceID, out invoiceEntry))
            {
                invoiceEntry = invoice;
                invoiceEntry.Variables = new Dictionary<int, double>();
                invoiceDictionary.Add(invoiceEntry.InvoiceID, invoiceEntry);
            }

            invoiceEntry.Variables.Add(variables.Key, variables.Value);
            return invoiceEntry;
        },
        splitOn: "VariablesId")
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: my bad. Edited my answer